# addEventListener by select not workting

Tags: html, select, addeventlistener

by running this code on flask, I am expecting to change tag  "No name submitted" relating to the selected option, that I select out of the drop down menu. Instead of there are no changes, if I click on one option.

Thanks for your help!

```
<body>
    <script> 
        document.addEventListener("change", function(){ 
            document.querySelector("#selectoption").onchange(){
            const channel = document.querySelector("#selectoption").value;
            document.querySelector("#displaychannel").innerHTML=channel;
            };
        });


    </script>

    <h1> channels </h1>

    <ul>
    {% for channel in channels%}
        <li>{{ channel }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    <form id="form2">
        <select id="select">
    {% for channel in channels%}
        <option id="selectoption" value={{ channel }}>{{ channel }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
        </select>

    </form>
    <a1>You are:</a1>
    <a1 id="displaychannel">No name submitted</a1>
</body>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#selectoption").onchange(){`…`}`?

Comment: Very nice! Thank you! Worked perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select the `select` to add an event listener to it. You can not add a `onchange` event listener to the `document`. You should never add an event listener inside an event listener as it will make the same function execute more and more times each times if the event is fired.

```
document.getElementById("selectoption").onchange = function(){...}
//or
document.getElementById("selectoption").addEventListener("change", function(event){...});
```

```html
<select id="selectoption">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<script>
document.getElementById("selectoption").onchange = function(){
 console.log(this.value);
}
</script>
```